# List editor and events of its items editors

Tags: backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-forms

I have a very simple model:

```
var ListItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    schema: {
        name: 'Text',
    }
});
```

and another simple model which has a list inside:

```
var Configuration = Backbone.Model.extend({
    schema: {
        list: {
            type:     'List',
            itemType: 'NestedModel',
            model:    ListItem
        }
    }
});
```

and a form:

```
var form = new Backbone.Form({ model: configuration }).render();
```

I need to listen to the events on the ListItem's "name" editor.

When I use this:

```
form.on('all', function() { console.log('print something') });
```

I did not get anything from the "name" editor.

I've also tried a lot of other events names but non of them was working in that case.

How can I listen to the change events on the ListItem's "name" editor?